# Efficient way to split string where individual words are separated by capitalizations or numbers and apply this to entire dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the team names are given as a string.  The rules to split string to get individual team names are

1. Every Capitalized character starts a new team
2. Every Numeric character starts a new string unless the previous
3. No team names after the first non-numeric or non-alphabetic character

My solution is below.  It works, but I am looking for pointers to improve

1. Can the whole split be done as a reg-ex
2. Anything faster that using apply.  I have seen some notes about speeding apply up using parallel version, but wondering if there is some faster way to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

def splitDfCap(next_row):
    new_team = ''
    team_list = []
    last_char_num = False
    for next_char in next_row.Teams:
        stop_current = re.match('[A-Z]', next_char) or (re.match('[0-9]', next_char) and not(last_char_num))
        if stop_current and len(new_team) > 0:
            team_list.append(new_team)
            new_team = ''
        
        if re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9]', next_char):
            new_team = new_team + next_char
            last_char_num = re.match('[0-9]', next_char)
        else:
            break
    
    if len(new_team) > 0:
        team_list.append(new_team)
                       
    return team_list
        

#Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'Population' : [1400, 100, 1000], 
                   'Teams' : ['YankeesMetsBrooklyn[]', 'Rays', 'GiantsAthletics49ers'], 
                   'Ad Market' : [10400, 2000, 8400]},
                  index = ['New York Area', 'Tampa Bay', 'SF Bay Area'])

#Create list of teams and then explode
df['Team List'] = df.apply(splitDfCap, axis='columns')
df = df.rename_axis(index='Region')\
       .explode('Team List')\
       .rename(columns={'Team List': 'Team'})\
       .drop(columns=['Teams'])
print(df)
```

```
Output is
               Population  Ad Market       Team
Region                                         
New York Area        1400      10400    Yankees
New York Area        1400      10400       Mets
New York Area        1400      10400   Brooklyn
Tampa Bay             100       2000       Rays
SF Bay Area          1000       8400     Giants
SF Bay Area          1000       8400  Athletics
SF Bay Area          1000       8400      49ers
```

Comment: Maybe try posting this on code review?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Population' : [1400, 100, 1000], 
                   'Teams' : ['YankeesMetsBrooklyn[]', 'Rays', 'GiantsAthletics49ers'], 
                   'Ad Market' : [10400, 2000, 8400]},
                  index = ['New York Area', 'Tampa Bay', 'SF Bay Area'])

df['Teams']=df.Teams.str.findall('(?:[A-Z]|\d+)[^A-Z\d+\W]*')
df = df.explode('Teams')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Region','Population','Ad Market','Team']
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris.  One issue with above solution is that it does not satisfy parsing rule #3 ```No team names after the first non-numeric or non-alphabetic character```

E.g also picks ```Dontpick``` in the example below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Population' : [1400, 100, 1000], 
                   'Teams' : ['YankeesMetsBrooklyn[]Dontpick', 'Rays', 'GiantsAthletics49ers'], 
                   'Ad Market' : [10400, 2000, 8400]},
                  index = ['New York Area', 'Tampa Bay', 'SF Bay Area'])
```